# how to make a ribbon like the one in office 2010

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ribbon

Does anyone know some good guides on making Ribbons that actually look good like the one in Office 2010?

Preferably non-Microsoft guides since I've read several already and wasn't too thrilled with the results or ease. Some things in particular that I've never seen replicated are the semi-transparent deselected tab headings, good high DPI scaling, and smooth window resizing, etc. Little things like that make or break the program!

I'm using the Windows Ribbon for WPF (October 2010) / Windows 7 / .NET 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some options to look into:

1. [DevExpress Ribbon](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Bar_Menu/)
2. [CodeProject Ribbon Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ribboncontrol.aspx)
3. [Ribbon API](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I ended up using the Ribbon for WPF. I didn't want to introduce third party stuff into my project really and I know that it isn't perfect but probably as close as I'm going to get for free.